# Else not raising errors in try-except-else

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I'm working with a special try-except-else block in python where I try to fetch an value and if I fail I try to create it to use later.

However, the creation process is not perfect (it actually fetches from the internet and might fail for several reasons) and I noticed that when this fails it is not raised. The only information I get is that the value is not defined

```
NameError: name 'value' is not defined
```

Since the error can be many, I would very much appreciate to see the full trackback for the error in the else clause

Please note: all tries can raise KeyError and the instantiation process cannot raise this error, it's always something else. Here is a sample code:

```
try:
    value = _list[key]

except KeyError:
    try:
        number = kwargs['number']  # A number might be parsed via kwargs
    except KeyError:
        clean_everything()
        value = None
        raise KeyError('Value not found! ' +
                       'Need a number to create new instance!')
    else:
        value = Value(number=number)  # This instantiation can raise other errors!
        _list[homeTeam] = _listnumber[number] = value  # Update lists for future reference.

finally:
    print value
```

Anyone got any ideas on why the else clause is not raising? Is there a better way to write this?

Thanks,

**EDIT:** Added treatment for value inside the nested try.
This is leading me to believe that nested tries doesn't work as the nested errors will only be raised after the outer-most finally.
i.e. inner errors are raised only after the outer try is completed.

This might lead to a new question: how can I properly raise an error inside an except clause?

Comment: If you get two `KeyError`s, what happens when the `finally` tries to use `value`?

Comment: Nothing, it doesn't get to the `finally` as it's raised in the nested `except`.

Comment: "it doesn't get to the `finally`" - no, it does. That's the whole point of `finally`.

Comment: hmm, indeed! I just ran a version with no kwargs['number'] and if raised the NameError... seems like the errors from the nested try are raised only after the finally...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to access `value` without first defining it indeed raises `NameError`. If `KeyError` is raised because `key` is not in `_list`, then `value` will never get defined in the `try` block. Because you redefine `value` in both of the `except` blocks, this should be OK there. However, your `finally` block does not redefine `value` before accessing it, so you would get a `NameError` there in the following cases:

- `value = _list[key]` raises an error other than `KeyError` (e.g. `NameError` when `_list` is not defined)
- `clean_everything()` raises any error
- `value = Value(number=number)` raises any error

You can define `value` before the `try` block so that it is always defined no matter what happens inside the `try` block.